# php loads before hitting ‘submit’ even when using if(isset($_GET["submit"])); ignores constant ‘GREETING’

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, isset

I have been working on this simple ‘get’ form for over a week and am calling uncle. I want the form to echo the GREETING constant before the user hits ‘submit’- i.e. when the page first loads. Even without hitting ‘submit’ the response for ‘no user input’ loads and ignores the GREETING. Here is my code w/out the if(isset($_GET[“submit”])).

When I add the if(isset..) the GREETING constant loads but all other actions are ignored.

Code w/out isset:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>A Simple Get Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="GetForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="GET">
1) What are the colors of the U.S. Flag?<br>
 <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="a" />a) red, white and blue<br />
 <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="b" />b) yellow, red and blue<br />
 <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="c" />c) blue, green and amber <br>
<input type="submit" value="GO" /><input type="reset" value="RESET" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?

define(ERROR, 'No answer was input for this question. Please select and answer.');
define(GREETING, 'Welcome to my simplest of php forms.');
$answer1=$_GET['Question1'];

if($answer1=="a")
{echo "You are correct.";  }

elseif ($answer1=="")
{echo ERROR. "" ; }

elseif ($answer1=="b" || $answer1=="c")
{echo "Your answer was incorrect."; }

else {echo GREETING. "";  }

?>
```

HERE is the code WITH the if(isset..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>A Simple Get Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="GetForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="GET">
1) What are the colors of the U.S. Flag?<br>
 <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="a" />a) red, white and blue<br />
 <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="b" />b) yellow, red and blue<br />
 <input type="radio" name="Question1" value="c" />c) blue, green and amber <br>
<input type="submit" value="GO" /><input type="reset" value="RESET" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?

define(ERROR, 'No answer was input for this question. Please select and answer.');
define(GREETING, 'Welcome to my simplest of php forms.');
$answer1=$_GET['Question1'];

if(isset($_GET["submit"]))

{
if($answer1=="a")
{echo "You are correct.";  }

elseif ($answer1=="")
{echo ERROR. "" ; }

elseif ($answer1=="b" || $answer1=="c")
{echo  "Your answer was incorrect."; }
}
else {echo GREETING. "";  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: You're using GET, which means that when you load the page for the first time, it's via a GET, and

```
$answer1=$_GET['Question1']
```

will get executed, making `$answer1` be `null`, because there's no `Question1` parameter in your URL.

Then  this comes up

```
elseif ($answer1=="")
```

and evaluates to true, because with a standard `==` equality test, `null == ""` is TRUE. So boom, you output a bogus error message.

You could avoid this, possibly, with

```
elseif ($answer1 === "")
```

Note the **THREE** `=` signs, meaning this is a strict equality test: data type AND value must match.

That or switch the form to using `POST` for submission, and then you can fence off the whole form processing section with

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... process form here
}
```

Comment: Thanks when I changed form method to 'POST' and added the ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') it worked awesomely. I could not get the $_GET form method to work at all using your suggestions. So thanks!